# Tornado 'Hello World' Error

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to run the following HelloWorld Script at Command Line

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I am getting the following error

```
File "helloworld.py", line 17, in ?
    import tornado.httpserver
  File "/home/username/public_html/tornado-1.2.1/tornado/httpserver.py", line 28, in ?
    from tornado import ioloop
  File "/home/username/public_html/tornado-1.2.1/tornado/ioloop.py", line 184
    action if action is not None else signal.SIG_DFL)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Brand New to `Python`, can someone explain what the problem being pointed out is? P.S. helloworld.py is in the `/home/username/public_html/tornado-1.2.1/` directory, and there is a `tornado` subdirectory in the same directory.

**Edit:** (Ignore this edit now)
The command i am running is

```
python helloworld.py
```

The result of `python -V`  is

Python 2.4.3

Unfortunately Tornado doesn't work with versions before 2.5 so this might be the problem. However, I have installed Python 2.6.6 How do I ensure that it is running with the correct version of Python and not the older one?

**EDIT II**

Now I have set Python to 2.6.6

and running

```
python helloworld.py
```

doesn't produce any output. The program just freezes at the command line.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: What version of python are you running, and what version of python does tornado require?

Comment: Your code works on Python 2.7.  Higher versions have other dependencies to run Tornado.

Comment: Ternary operators (a if b else c) were introduced in Python 2.5.  Are you running older than 2.5?

Comment: running 2.6.6... According to the official website "Tornado runs on Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2." so don't think this is an issue

Comment: Can you put 2 things into your question? Let us know the command you're doing to run it, and also paste in the results of running python -V

Comment: Thanks Jordan!..I have edited the question to include the information you asked for...It turns out that a different version of python than i thought was running. Now I need to know how to ensure that the right version is being used...see edit for details!

Comment: what distribution are you running?

Comment: Are you sure the program "freezes", or is just waiting to serve requests?  Have you tried connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8888 on the machine running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found out yourself, the problem is that python 2.4 does not support the conditional expression operator.

How you can switch to another Python version depends on your system. On debian and Ubuntu, you can edit `/usr/share/python/debian_defaults`. On all Linux systems, you can remove /usr/bin/python and link to the version you'd like:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.dist
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.5 /usr/bin/python
```

Alternatively, you can modify the `PATH` environment variable to contain a directory with the desired `python` binary before `/usr/bin` (this is probably the way to go on Windows). You can make this permanent by editing `~/.profile` (at every login) or `~/.bashrc` (in interactive, bash shells).

Comment: I have modified the Path to ensure that its Python 2.6.6. Now i run the program and nothing happens!...Please see question for details.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder When you enter `python` at your prompt, does nothing happen, too? If so, please post the output of `ls -l $(which python)`. Also, the output of `strace python` (optionally with your program) would be of invaluable help. Also, please post the modified path (the output of `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: Typing "python" takes me to the python command line prompt..so it acts as expected. I did export PATH = $HOME/py26/bin:$PATH. the strace seems way too long to post...what should i look for?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder You can post the full output at http://pastebin.com/ . Also, you said "nothing happens". I assumed you meant no syscalls at all, but now I'm not that sure. What exactly *did* you mean? If you add a few `print` statements to your program, are they displayed?

Answer (score 1):

To get Python 2.6 as default make sure you've mapped `python` to `/usr/bin/python2.6` in your `.bash_rc`.

If you're trying to fix this, you'll need to go through and swap out the conditional operator:

```
if seconds is not None:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,
                      action if action is not None else signal.SIG_DFL)
```

This syntax (`action if action is not None else signal.SIG_DFL`) is only available in Python 2.>=5

The alt? Not as nice but workable:

```
if seconds is not None:
        if action is not None:
            tmpaction = action
        else
            tmpaction = signal.SIG_DFL
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,tmpaction)
```

I HIGHLY RECOMMEND THAT YOU SIMPLY UPGRADE TO THE LATEST VERSION OF PYTHON. THERE IS NO GUARANTEE THAT YOU WON'T FIND OTHER ISSUES. (Unless, of course, you want the learning experience).

Comment: I have modified the Path to ensure that its Python 2.6.6. Now i run the program and nothing happens!...Please see question for details.